# Trigger Azure DevOps pipeline to run only when PR is raised

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, cicd

I want my pipeline to run *only* when a PR is raised from any source branch to the `develop` branch. I do not want anything to run after the PR is merged.

This is what I have:

```
trigger: none

pr:
  branches:
    include:
    - develop
```

However, with this, nothing runs when I raise a PR from a source branch to develop...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve that for your `develop` branch by configuring `branch policies`!
You have build validation part where you specify the rule and select yaml file to be executed when PR is created on that branch.

You can find everything on [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/branch-policies?view=azure-devops&tabs=browser#build-validation).

Comment: Thanks - yes I figured this would be one solution - however, is it not possible to define the same behaviour in the yaml code without a branch policy?

Comment: I'm affraid not. If you look into the branch triggers I think that they say for pr triggers this is the only way. But you can check again.

Comment: PR triggers in Azure yaml pipelines are only supported for GitHub and Bitbucket repositories, sadly. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/triggers?view=azure-devops#classic-build-pipelines-and-yaml-pipelines where it has three different links for GitHub/Azure Repos/Bitbucket for how to handle PR triggers